# Command line interface-based way to desaturate and posterize an image?

Tags: color, gimp, software-recommendation

This is by far my most common task, and I'd say I've wasted about 1000 mouse clicks on it in my raster-based program.

Because it's so common for me to start off [desaturating](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Color2BW/) an image and then [posterizing](http://manual.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-posterize.html) it, I'd like to write a shell script that does the same, that way I can process an entire directory automagically and simply get on with my work... There are only so many hours in the day. If I can make my computer do all the mouse clicks for me, go away and drink a few cups of coffee while it does so, then come back to it, that's infinitely better for me.

So how can I accomplish these two tasks using the CLI?

Comment: It'd help to mention GIMP in your question. Took me a few minutes to figure out what app you were using! I don't have an answer for you but am interesting in seeing if others come up with. An easy way to script The GIMP would be useful. There is Script-Fu, though I haven't looked at that in much detail: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-script-fu.html

Comment: What are doing this with now? There might be scripting-based, non-CLI options available to you in your current set of tools. This, of course, largely depends on whether your application of choice offers an API to target a script.

Comment: @ixt "Command line" might be a reasonable translation that works on a non-IT-centric site.

Comment: @DA01, I'm not asking for an application-specific method. Unfortunately the graphics design community does not seem to have vocabulary that crosses the boundaries drawn by operating systems.

Comment: Uh...you tagged in GIMP. Are you not using The GIMP?

Comment: @DA01 I tagged it GIMP because, yes, I am using the GIMP. That doesn't mean that half of the algorithms on windows-based programs aren't roughly equivalent, or that the names matter more than the processes at work. I ended up choosing ImageMagick for the job. See? The same classes of visual transformations is involved. Perhaps a community wiki page of system-agnostic graphic design terms is needed, as in this other stack-exchange site http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/glossary-of-common-rpg-terminology

Comment: @Pekka I decided that the term 'command-line' is GUI-centric. After all, would you go around saying 'graphical user interface'? So with the CLI. If I can say GUI, I should be able to say CLI.

Comment: I'd maybe word it as "scriptable image processing that can handle color desaturation".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is the most awesome and powerful CLI image editing tool I know. It runs on most operating systems.

- For desaturation, it looks like a [`-colorspace gray`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace) is the tool of choice but desaturation is apparently a more complex topic than one might think. There is a discussion on the right method(s) [here](http://studio.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17407)
- There are examples for posterizing in the docs:

  - Using the [`-posterize` parameter](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#posterize)
  - [Color quantization main chapter](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#colors)

Comment: +1 for linking to the discussion about desaturation. I already knew how to do it this way and found it unsatisfactory since ImageMagick doesn't give you as many options for desaturation as GIMP does. Otherwise the -posterize parameter does exactly what I need. So I may end up doing it by using one big script that makes a call to both GIMP and ImageMagick.

Comment: @ixt I can relate! I never managed to get my head around the alchemies of GIMP, either.  :)

Comment: Ever since I learned of ImageMagick I use it all the time in Python scripts to batch process entire directories of images.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically called batch processing and GIMP supports it. More info:

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: Though I love the idea of LISP, I can never quite read it well enough to write anything in it... http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?t=84073&page=1 was more handy, because it talks about Python-based GIMP batch scripting... Still haven't cracked this problem though.